# Push notification is queued on iphone

Tags: php, ios, iphone

Hi I am using EasyAPNs with PHP script. Before I use to get notification on my iOS device but very recently I am not getting the notification. All i have been getting this message stored in database:

```
message:- {"aps":{"alert":"This is tset for push not.."},"acme2":["bang","whiz"]}
status:- queued
```

Comment: Is your push notification certificate still valid?